# signin with Linkedin code give me html validation error

Tags: javascript, html, oauth-2.0, w3c-validation, linkedin-api

I'm using https://validator.w3.org to validate my HTML 5 website. I'm using Linkedin javascript login SDK. I followed this tutorial https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/signin-with-linkedin

I got this error

> The text content of element script was not in the required format: Expected space, tab, newline, or slash but found a instead.

in this code block

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//platform.linkedin.com/in.js">
  api_key: YOUR_API_KEY_HERE
  authorize: true
  onLoad: onLinkedInLoad
</script>
```

The problem that this code is provided by the tutorial.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved this problem by separating the loading of the API and the initiation of the API.

```
<script src="http://platform.linkedin.com/in.js?async=true"></script>

<script>
IN.init({
    api_key: 'YOUR_API_KEY_HERE',
    onLoad: onLinkedInLoad,
    authorize: true,
    scope: 'r_basicprofile r_fullprofile r_emailaddress r_contactinfo',
});
</script>
```

this code is valid code by W3C